# Is website for online game guides doable in WordPress?

Tags: plugins, theme-development, customization

It will almost work as blog but:

Writers will work only with one kind of content "guide".
They will write it in markup language with custom tags that will be replaced by presets.
They will choose game version they write against. When game will be updated presets will also be updated to much new game mechanics. Writers will be notified about such changes with list of changes relevant to their guide (based on the list of tags used, that got changed!).
Since whole content (with comments) could be moderated, there may be need for ranks, badges, points, etc. for users, so they would like to moderate it themselfs.

Readers will search for guides via rating, game version, categories, etc. (Creation date will be irrelevant!), will rate and comment them.

As you can see both writers and readers will be users to my website. And main selling point will be:

- Help with keeping guides up to date for writers.
- Help with providing game data via simple tags for writers (so they write less, and make less mistakes)
- Help with searching for relevant guides for readers.

As for admins, modderators:

- Keeping tags and presets up to date will be critical (probably there will be new set of those for every game update -- every 2-3 months)
- Moderating guides is requirement, moderating every comment may be requirement, so ability to offload such work onto users themselfs would be very good! (Like peer review for guides).

**Can I do such website in WordPress?**
Will it require much work with customization?

PS If you know better tags, title for this question change them or leave comment below!

Comment: Your question is far to broad for a single answer. Please split it into answerable questions.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. That's an easy ask of Wordpress. You could design a theme yourself, or you could use one of many magazine themes available on the Internet from sites such as [woothemes](http://zfer.us/5WvQN)?

There are also loads of plugins that might be useful at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/

Comment: Theme is least of my problems :D I'm more worried about markup and custom tags.

Comment: So the plugins directory is the place for you...in answer to your questions ... Yes, Wordpress is more than suitable.

Comment: Also, a theme is a lot more than just making it look pretty. A theme in Wordpress can define the entire structure of your site. You should look into that before you throw too much time into plugins.